# Knowing the null space, find an RREF

Tags: linear-algebra

It is easy to find the null space of the matrix by reducing it to RREF. Now I was thinking about the opposite problem. **Find the matrix from its null space**. Here are my thoughts:

---

If the matrix for a particular null-space exist, there should be infinite amount of such matrices as elementary row operations preserve the null space.

So now my question is reduced to **find the RREF of a matrix from the null space**, which also looks like has many solutions. This is because for an $n \times m$ matrix, the null space is $m \times k$ where $k$ is the number of non-pivot columns (and therefore $k <= m$). So if I have a RREF which satisfy a particular null space I can just add rows of 0 to this RREF to have many other RREFs.

So now my question is reduced **find the RREF of a particular size from the null space** which I can't resolve in a general way.

---

My questions are:
 - are my abovementioned thoughts correct?
 - is there an algorithm to find RREF of particular size, knowing the null space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible strategy:

Suppose we know the null space, and a basis is $\{ w_1, \ldots, w_{n-r}\}$.

Let $W=\begin{bmatrix} w_1^T\\ \vdots \\ w_{n-r}^T\end{bmatrix}$, where $W\in \mathbb{R}^{(n-r)\times n}$.

We can find a basis for the nullspace of $W$, $\{v_1, \ldots, v_r\}$.

These vectors satisfies $v_i^Tw_j=0 \,\forall i,j$.

That is if we let $B=\begin{bmatrix} v_1^T\\\vdots \\ v_r^T\end{bmatrix}$, then we have $Bw_i=0$ where $B\in \mathbb{R}^{r \times n}$.

We can compute the RREF of $B$ to find the desired matrix, $R \in \mathbb{R}^{r\times n}$. Now, if we we want to find a matrix of size that has more than $r$ rows, we just have to append zero rows to $R$ to construct that matrix.